# ASP.NET User Control Value

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, user-controls

I created a DatePicker user control (ASP code below, no code behind) which is simply a textbox, image button, and a sometimes visible calendar.

```
<%@ Control Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" _
    CodeBehind="myDatePicker.ascx.vb"
    Inherits="Website.myDate" %>

<%@ Register assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" _
    tagprefix="asp" %>

<asp:TextBox ID="Date1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Calendar_scheduleHS.png" />

<asp:CalendarExtender ID="Date1_CalendarExtender" runat="server" Enabled="True" 
    TargetControlID="Date1" PopupButtonID="Image1"  >
</asp:CalendarExtender>
```

Can I somehow tie or pass the value of the TextBox as the value of the whole control to use in the calling code?

**EDIT:** My actual goal here is to be able to tie the SelectedDate as a parameter of a database query.  I was able to select values for the other parameters in a controls dropdown list in a query parameter configuration window.

Comment: Do you want to expose a property on the user control representing the selected date?

Comment: That sounds like it would work.  Please elaborate.

Comment: I was asking if you're trying to give access to the selected date from OUTSIDE the userControl. Something like myDatePicker.SelectedDate

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you would need to create on the code behind of your user control a property like this

```
Public ReadOnly Property SelectedDate() As String
        Get
            Dim format As String = "MM/dd/yyyy" 'Your format
            Dim _selectedDate As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(Date1.Text, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
            Return _selectedDate
        End Get
End Property
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying you want to get the date from the CalendarExtender? If so, you can use the SelectedDate property on the CalendarExtender for that.